# Why is my C++ QuickSort function for strings stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, string, quicksort

I am having problems with using a QuickSort function to organize Strings in C++

Been using a couple of YT tutorials and internet examples to build this function, but it keeps repeating indefinetly, i get the logic of why it repeats itself, but i don't know how to fix it so it stops doing so

Would really appreciate if someone could point out if i am doing something worng or how to fix it

```
struct Personaslista
{
    std::string Nombre;
    int EspacioArreglo = 0;
} X[CantidadDePersonas];


void QUICKSORT(int Primero, int Ultimo, int B)
{
    int I, J, Central = 0;
    //const wchar_t* Pivote;
    std::string PIVOTE;

    Central = (Primero + Ultimo) / 2; //Posición central del arreglo

    //Agarrar valor del medio del Arreglo

    //Pivote = X[Central].Clave;
    //Pivote = X[Central].Clave;
    PIVOTE = X[Central].Nombre;

    //Separar Segmentos

    I = Primero;
    J = Ultimo;


    do
    {
        //Separar el Arreglo en 2

        while (X[I].Nombre <= PIVOTE) //Valores Menores al Pivote
        {
            I++;
        }
        while (X[J].Nombre > PIVOTE) //Valores Mayores al Pivote
        {
            J--;
        }

        
        if (X[I].Nombre <= X[J].Nombre)
        {
            //const wchar_t* Temp;
            std::string Temp;
            int Poral;
            Temp = X[I].Nombre;
            Poral = X[I].EspacioArreglo;
            X[I].Nombre = X[J].Nombre;
            X[I].EspacioArreglo = X[J].EspacioArreglo;
            X[J].Nombre = Temp;
            X[J].EspacioArreglo = Poral;
            I++;
            J--;

        }


    } while (I <= J);

    if (Primero < J)
    {
        //Primero = J;
        QUICKSORT(Primero, J, B);
    }

    if (I < Ultimo)
    {
        
        QUICKSORT(I, Ultimo, B);
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Start simple and stupid: Does the quicksort work with integers? By the way, YT was a skate courier. If you want coding advice, talk to Hiro or Da5id.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose the problem accurately since the code seems to be written in Spanish. I would suggest splitting your code into separate *helper* functions (function decomposition) and go on from there...for instance, one function gets the pivot, one function does the partition, and so on

Comment: Side note: Uppercase variable names and all caps for function prototypes are not desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters, your code did not even compile. You are missing variables? I tried to fix it and also flipped the directions of a few inequalities (assuming you want the sort to be in ascending order).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define CantidadDePersonas 8

struct Personaslista {
  string Nombre;
  int EspacioArreglo;
} X[CantidadDePersonas];

void QUICKSORT(int Primero, int Ultimo, int B) {
  int I, J, Central = 0;
  string PIVOTE;

  Central = (Primero + Ultimo) / 2; // Posición central del arreglo

  // Agarrar valor del medio del Arreglo

  // Pivote = X[Central].Clave;
  // Pivote = X[Central].Clave;
  PIVOTE = X[Central].Nombre;

  // Separar Segmentos

  I = Primero;
  J = Ultimo;
  do { // Separar el Arreglo en 2
    // Valores Menores al Pivote
    while (X[I].Nombre <= PIVOTE) {
      I++;
    } // Valores Mayores al Pivote
    while (X[J].Nombre > PIVOTE) {
      J--;
    }
    if (X[I].Nombre > X[J].Nombre) {
      // const wchar_t* Temp;
      string Temp;
      int Poral;
      Temp = X[I].Nombre;
      Poral = X[I].EspacioArreglo;
      X[I].Nombre = X[J].Nombre;
      X[I].EspacioArreglo = X[J].EspacioArreglo;
      X[J].Nombre = Temp;
      X[J].EspacioArreglo = Poral;
      I++;
      J--;
    }
  } while (I <= J);
  if (Primero > J) {
    // Primero = J;
    QUICKSORT(Primero, J, B);
  }
  if (I > Ultimo) {
    QUICKSORT(I, Ultimo, B);
  }
  return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i = 72;
  struct Personaslista *ptr = X;
  struct Personaslista *endPtr = X + sizeof(X) / sizeof(X[0]);
  while (ptr < endPtr) {
    (*ptr).EspacioArreglo = i - 65;
    (*ptr).Nombre = (char)i;
    cout << (*ptr).EspacioArreglo << ", " << (*ptr).Nombre << endl;
    i--;
    ptr++;
  }
  cout << "---" << endl;
  QUICKSORT(0, CantidadDePersonas - 1, -1);

  ptr = X;
  while (ptr < endPtr) {
    cout << (*ptr).EspacioArreglo << ", " << (*ptr).Nombre << endl;
    ptr++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You also never really initialised `Nombre`. Note that you are still never really using the recursive variable `B`. This works when there are no recursive calls.

```bash
g++ temp.cpp -o temp.out
./temp.out
```

Now prints,

```
7, H
6, G
5, F
4, E
3, D
2, C
1, B
0, A
---
0, A
1, B
2, C
4, E
5, F
3, D
6, G
7, H
```

Can you implement the recursion correctly now?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the main `do` loop in the `QUICKSORT` method and suppose that `X[I].Nombre > PIVOTE` and `X[J].Nombre < PIVOTE`.

Neither of the `while` loops will change `I` or `J` and the `if` condition will also be `false`. Thus, if `I <= J`, the loop will continue forever.

I think the partitioning code should be closer to something like this,

```cpp
while (true) {
    while (I < J and X[I].Nombre <= PIVOTE) ++I;
    while (I < J and X[J].Nombre > PIVOTE) ++J;
    if (I >= J)
        break;
    std::swap(X[I], X[J]);
    ++I;
    ++J;
}
```

It is pretty easy to verify that this loop is guaranteed to terminate.

**Update**

If I were developing this code, I would probably break it into a partition function and sort function like the following sample code. And, I would write a couple test routines so I could check the results of the individual functions.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#undef NDEBUG
#include <cassert>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

using std::cout, std::endl;

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& data) {
    os << "[ ";
    for (auto elem : data)
        os << elem << " ";
    os << "]";
    return os;
}

int *partition(int *first, int *last, int value) {
    while (true) {
        while (*first < value)
            ++first;
        while (value < *last)
            --last;
        if (first >= last)
            return last;
        std::swap(*first, *last);
        ++first;
        --last;
    }
}

void check_partition(int *first, int *split, int *last, int value) {
    while (first <= split) {
        assert(*first <= value);
        ++first;
    }

    while (first <= last) {
        assert(*first >= value);
        ++first;
    }
}

void qsort(int *first, int *last) {
    if (first < last) {
        auto pivot = *(first + (last - first) / 2);
        auto split = partition(first, last, pivot);
        check_partition(first, split, last, pivot);
        qsort(first, split);
        qsort(split + 1, last);
    }
}

void check_sort(int *first, int *last) {
    while (first < last) {
        assert(*first <= *(first + 1));
        ++first;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> data(30);
    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), [n=0]() mutable { return n++; });
    std::shuffle(data.begin(), data.end(), std::mt19937_64{});
    cout << data <<  endl;

    auto first = &data[0];
    auto last = first + data.size() - 1;
    auto pivot = data.size() / 2;
    auto split = partition(first, last, pivot);
    check_partition(first, split, last, pivot);
    cout << data <<  endl;

    std::shuffle(data.begin(), data.end(), std::mt19937_64{});
    qsort(first, last);
    check_sort(first, last);
    cout << data <<  endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
[ 6 29 26 21 16 27 7 13 20 2 9 22 24 1 4 28 25 19 12 8 10 15 5 0 17 23 11 18 3 14 ]
[ 6 14 3 11 0 5 7 13 15 2 9 10 8 1 4 12 25 19 28 24 22 20 27 16 17 23 21 18 26 29 ]
[ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 ]
```